# No qualifying bean of type "java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I use am trying to implement **Spring Data** in my project(I use CrudRepository and Repository) and I'm stucked getting these error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying 
   bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, 
   ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
   Dependency annotations: {}
```

(full log will be bellow).

Those are my interfaces of **Repository**:

```
public interface KotSelects extends Repository<Kot, Long> {
    Kot findById(Long id);
    List<Kot> findAll();
    Integer countDistinctByIdNotNull();
}
```

And **CrudRepository**:

```
public interface KotInserts extends CrudRepository<Kot, Long> { }
```

I use Sping MVC for building my project and this is my **aplication context file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.itlifestyle" /> <!-- Chcemy automatycznie obsługiwać wszystkie klasy z adnotacjami w tym pakiecie -->
    <context:annotation-config /> <!-- To na przyszłość, pozwoli nam korzystać z adnotacji także w klasach, które byśmy skonfigurowali ręcznie -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--<bean id = "kotDAO" classnet.itlifestyle.koty.KotDAOtDAO" />-->
    <!--<bean id="kotDAO" clanet.itlifestyle.koty.KotDAOtDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vhrab"/>
        <property name="username" value="vhrab" />
        <property name="password" value="youshallnotpass" />
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.itlifestyle.koty.domain" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.itlifestyle.koty.dao"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/style1/" />
</beans>
```

This is my **pom-file** for my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.itlifestyle</groupId>
    <artifactId>Koty</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>koty-domain</module>
        <module>koty-application</module>
        <module>koty-webapp</module>
    </modules>
    <name>KotApplication</name>
    <url>http://kobietydokodu.pl/7-maven-i-tajemnice-pliku-pom-xml/</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Spring Object/Relational Mapping for JPA -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--SpringData dependency-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.kot.app.MainClass</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And **log from server**:

```
sie 23, 2017 3:39:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kotyController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kotDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kotDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daoSel'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kotSelects': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1762)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kotDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daoSel'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kotSelects': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kotSelects': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 86 more

sie 23, 2017 3:39:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

I have tried to lover Spring-core and all dependencies of org.springframework to version similar of spring-data-jpa and spring-data-commons as it is suggested here: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103223/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-java-lang-classorg-springframework-data-repository

My class where I have an `@Autowire` fields(cuted out getters and setters to reduce code):

```
@Repository
public class KotDAO{
    @Autowired
    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private KotSelects daoSel;

    @Autowired
    private KotInserts daoIns;

    private List<Kot> koty = new ArrayList<Kot>();

    public void insert(Kot kot){ daoIns.save(kot);}

    public Kot getKotById(Long id){ return daoSel.findById(id);}

    public List<Kot> getKotAll(){ return daoSel.findAll();}

    public Integer getLiczbaKotow(){return daoSel.countDistinctByIdNotNull();}

}
```

**Project structure:**

[General structure][1]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56KdB.png
```

[koty-application module tree][2]

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AQXU.png
```

[koty-domain module tree][3]

```
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/10JeK.png
```

[koty-webapp module tree][4]

```
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBSRo.png
```

EDIT: 
1. Tried to remove @Repository adnotation over interfaces, that extends Repository and CrudRepository. Doesn't work for me.

P.S. Sorry for links. Stack says I have not enough reputation :D

Comment: do you have implementations of the repositories? For me it works when annotating the implementing classes.

Comment: How do you autowire the repositories?

Comment: @JackFlamp As I have read it is the Spring data who creates the implementation classes of those interfaces for me based on methods name

Comment: @AndrewTobilko You mean that my `Repository<Kot, Long>` is not a proper way of specifying types?

Comment: @StanislavL edited post. Added class wich have `@Autowired` fields

Comment: try removing @Repository from interface which extends CrudRepository. and do the same with the second one.

Comment: @ArslanAnjum thanks for your suggestion, tried to do these solution, but it doesn't work in my case

Comment: also change the interface which extends Repository to CrudRepository

Comment: @ArslanAnjum it doesn't make sense, because I want to have access to Repository abilities(methods) as it shown here:
[link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)
And CrudRepository offers only these methods:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts
As far as I understand of course.
And by the way, CrudRepository extends Repository interface, so it must be working anyway.

Comment: ok. what is the package of kotSelects and kotInserts?

Comment: they should be inside net.itlifestyle.koty.dao

Comment: @ArslanAnjum I added project structure to the post. Yes,they are, but in different package(I created a interfaces package) in relation to KotDAO class that uses these interfaces, but imports are working fine and I get no error.

Comment: you have mentioned in application context file that jpa repositories would be in  <jpa:repositories base-package="net.itlifestyle.koty.dao"/> so they should be in this package. Also see this sample project which is exposing certain entities using spring data rest. https://github.com/ArslanAnjum/angularSpringApi

Comment: @ArslanAnjum I tried to change these path `<jpa:repositories base-package="net.itlifestyle.koty.dao"/> `  to `<jpa:repositories base-package="net.itlifestyle.koty.dao.interfaces"/> `(where I have my interfaces), but I still got the same errors.

Comment: can you upload your code to github. give me the link and I would check it

Comment: @ArslanAnjum [spring-data branch](https://github.com/vhrabovyy/springmvckoty/tree/spring-data)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no reason to use @org.springframework.stereotype.Repository in thoses classes, that annotation is often use on the implementation. I recommend set your classes as the follow:

```
public interface KotInserts extends CrudRepository<Kot, Long> { }
```

and

```
public interface KotSelects extends Repository<Kot, Long> {...}
```

Spring data must see this classes thanks to the
*jpa:repositories base-package="net.itlifestyle.koty.dao"* and manage them (the implementation is hidden).

Comment: I tried these solution, but it doesn't worked for me. I'm thinking about if springframework doesn't know wich `<jpa:repositories base-package="net.itlifestyle.koty.dao"/>` or  `<context:component-scan base-package="net.itlifestyle" />` handles these interfaces(I have relation's shown in my IDE from eg. KotSelects to JPA and Context tags...

Comment: check this link and compare your configuration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049778/how-to-configure-spring-data-jpa-using-xml.